# WPF to UWP Visual Studio conversion build error

Tags: wpf, uwp, visual-studio-2017, desktop-bridge

im following this [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) tutorial to covert my WPF to UWP

I go this build error when trying to build the app.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: Item named 'themes/lightbrushes.baml' of 
type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource file 
because it is not serializable.
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo 
reader, IResourceWriter writer)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo 
reader, String filename)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile, 
String outFileOrDir)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, 
ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 
outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String 
resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, 
Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log, 
ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs, List`1 
outputs, Boolean sourcePath, String language, String namespacename, String 
resourcesNamespace, String filename, String classname, Boolean publicClass, 
Boolean extractingResWFiles, String resWOutputDirectory)
at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecution
Host.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.
<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()   Deployment.Bridge   C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets    1251
```

Note that 'themes/lightbrushes.baml' is not part of the app files
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to figure out what the "themes/lightbrushes.baml" is. If it's not part of your app files then where it comes from?

Comment: @Scavenger probably a wpf dictionary resource bundled in one of the dependancies. I search for it couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: but even if its part of my dependancies, where do we have this error ? how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar behavior while trying to convert satellite assemblies to PRIs.

You can try to disable this adding the next property to your jsproj file:

```
 <AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>false</AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>
```